# React-native Facebook sdk Login Button not working

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am trying to use `react-native-fbsdk` to login. I followed the steps from [React Native FBSDK](https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk). I got no error from xcode when I run it.

When I run `react-native run-ios` I have no error and I can even see facebook `Login Button` but when I click on the button, it doesn't bring me to the facebook login page. Nothing happens. Below is my code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View} from 'react-native';
import { LoginButton, AccessToken } from 'react-native-fbsdk';

export default class App extends Component<Props> {

  loginFacebook(){
  LoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(["public_profile"]).then(
    function(result) {
      if (result.isCancelled) {
        console.log("Login cancelled");
      } else {
        console.log(
          "Login success with permissions: " +
            result.grantedPermissions.toString()
        );
      }
    },
    function(error) {
      console.log("Login fail with error: " + error);
    }
  );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
      <LoginButton
          onLoginFinished={
            (error, result) => {
              if (error) {
                console.log("login has error: " + result.error);
              } else if (result.isCancelled) {
                console.log("login is cancelled.");
              } else {
                AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().then(
                  (data) => {
                    console.log(data.accessToken.toString())
                  }
                )
              }
            }
          }
          onLogoutFinished={() => console.log("logout.")}/>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
});
```

Any idea what is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. I don't know how much time I waste fixing this!

It turns out that its a bug with `FacebookSDKs-iOS-4.39.0` I had to downgrade it to `FacebookSDKs-iOS-4.38.0`.

[From this website](http://download%20here) I downloaded older version and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to use this code from fbsdk, it pass some props to the button, you may forget to do it:

```
<LoginButton
          onLoginFinished={
            (error, result) => {
              if (error) {
                console.log("login has error: " + result.error);
              } else if (result.isCancelled) {
                console.log("login is cancelled.");
              } else {
                AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().then(
                  (data) => {
                    console.log(data.accessToken.toString())
                  }
                )
              }
            }
          }
          onLogoutFinished={() => console.log("logout.")}/>
```

Other way you can try to use the LoginManager instead, by using this code: 
Create a button for facebook login:

```
<button onclick={this.loginFacebook}> </button>
```

Create a function for Facebook login:

```
loginFacebook(){
LoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(["public_profile"]).then(
  function(result) {
    if (result.isCancelled) {
      console.log("Login cancelled");
    } else {
      console.log(
        "Login success with permissions: " +
          result.grantedPermissions.toString()
      );
    }
  },
  function(error) {
    console.log("Login fail with error: " + error);
  }
);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I tried the code it but throws me an error `Cannot read property 'error' of null`

Comment: Can you put your code somewhere? I will check for you.

Comment: Can you create another button (<button onclick={this.loginFacebook}> </button>) and import {LoginManager } as well to test the function loginFacebook() ?

Comment: I did `<Button onPress={this.loginFacebook} title="Login"> </Button>` but nothing happens when I click the button.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code. If not thing happend I think you miss something when you do the install the lib. Try to re-install fbsdk again, npm start --clear-cache, and run the project again.

Comment: I successfully managed to use the code above or the code used in the example from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/react-native/login in both cases the result is that a modal with a loading image is prompted for a while till it terminate with error `Login fail with error: Error: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`. I am trying on local using Android Studio emulator. What I should be supposed to see after the click? The app should open the device browser to input access data? Is it possible to test this flow in an emulator?

Answer (score -1):

I fixed this by running application from terminal `react-native run-android`

I work with:
"react-native": "0.60.5",
"react-native-fbsdk": "^1.0.4"